# Is it possible to change the sys.version of google colab to 3.7? I need to import stellargraph but it keeps saying "no module named: distutils.util"

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-3.10

I am trying to use this in google colab

`%pip install -q stellargraph[demos]==1.3.0b`

However, disutils is declared as a legacy module in Python 3.10 so it keeps on showing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
```

Therefore, I was hoping if there is a way to change sys.version of colab to Python 3.7.
Thank you!